# Using AWS Cognito in a Lambda function with npm

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito in a Lambda function to authorize a user.

I have some sample code from a Udemy Course (no longer available): https://www.udemy.com/minimum-viable-aws-cognito-user-auth-in-javascript

The code uses the script files:

aws-cognito-sdk.min.js
amazon-cognito-identity.min.js

The second seems to available by npm as: amazon-cognito-identity-js

The first file is supposed to be a cut down version of the aws-sdk with just the Cognito api components. The full aws-sdk is available from npm as: aws-sdk but I cannot find the cutdown version in npm.

Is the cutdown file: aws-cognito-sdk.min.js available in npm?

EDIT:
According to Russell I should use the aws-sdk package.

So if I have code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var authenticationDetails = new AWS.AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
```

I get the error:

Cannot read property 'CognitoIdentityServiceProvider' of undefined

What is the correct path to AuthenticationDetails?

Comment: I said the cognito identity package depends on it (which means npm downloads that package too). You don't need to require it, you can simply use import statements.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code from the Udemy course to make your question more complete and useful. The Udemy course is no longer available and so is not a possible resource for someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working.

package.json needs dependencies:

```
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.31.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.182.0",
```

AWS Lambda does not use Javascript ES6 and so you can't use the 'import' keyword.

```
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

        var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
        var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
        var AuthenticationDetails = AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails;
        var CognitoUser = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;

        var poolData = {
            UserPoolId: 'THE USER POOL ID',
            ClientId: 'THE CLIENT ID'
        };
        var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);

        AWS.config.region = 'AWS_REGION';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'THE USERPOOL ID',
        });
        var email = "someone@somewhere.com";
        var password = "password";

        var authenticationData = {
            Username: email,
            Password: password
        };
        var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

        var userData = {
            Username: email,
            Pool: userPool
        };

        var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

        console.log(result);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
              console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
              callback(null, result);
            },

            onFailure: function (err) {
              console.log('Login error: ' + err);
              callback(null, result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't `AmazonCognitoIdentity` comes with `const AWS = require('aws-sdk')` ?

Answer (score 5):

For Lambdas use the `aws-sdk` module as such:

```
const { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } = require('aws-sdk')
//or 
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = require('aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider') // Much smaller size
```

For authentication use the [AdminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) method.

```
  const cognitoProvider =  new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
      apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
      accessKeyId:...
      secretAccessKey: ...
      region:...
    })

    await cognitoProvider.adminInitiateAuth(...)
```

The [`amazon-cognito-identity-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) package is meant for frontend clients (React, React Native, etc). It contains only the functionality necessary to connect to Cognito. It does not require the `aws-sdk` module (unless you need extra features).

While you may be able to use the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` for your use case it's far from ideal as you are just pretending to be an unauthenticated user with limited functionality compared to loading the admin method using your api key thereby providing you with much more functionality.

Comment: this is better then marked answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to the amazon-cognito-identity-js npm package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

The NPM package includes both files.

The package includes the cognito SDK calls (aws-cognito-sdk). It also depends on the core AWS SDK.

Comment: Added aws-sdk and my current result in EDIT above

Comment: I'm using Lambda on AWS. Actually developing in AWS Cloud9 IDE

Comment: The following is a good example of using it as a service in an Angular2 project:https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart/blob/master/src/app/service/cognito.service.ts

Comment: The following describes how to use it in basic Javascript: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html

Comment: And that tutorial includes a full code sample: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js